The Name "Havaya Tzeva'ot'" in the evening Shema
In the evening prayer for Shema, where we praise Hashem for bringing the night, etc, we then say 'Havaya Tzeva'ot' is your Name. Why is this His Name in this context?

I always assumed the pshat of it was that "legions" = stars.

As an intro to my answer, there is a machloket as to if Tzeva'ot is Hashem's name or not. The Gemera in Shevuot 35b says:

רבי יוסי אומר צבאות כולו נמחק שלא נקרא צבאות אלא על שם ישראל שנאמר (שמות ז, ד) והוצאתי את צבאותי את עמי בני ישראל מארץ מצרים אמר שמואל אין הלכה כרבי יוסי

Rabbi Yosei says: The word tzevaot may be erased in its entirety, as God is called Tzevaot only in the context of the children of Israel, and it is not an independent name of God, as it is stated: “And I shall bring forth My hosts [tzivotai], My people the children of Israel, out of the land of Egypt” (Exodus 7:4). Shmuel says: The halakha is not in accordance with the opinion of Rabbi Yosei.
The Rambam in Yesodei Hatorah 6:2 says that Tzeva'ot' is Hashem's name and we don't pasken like Rebbi Yossi.
So why use Tzeva'ot' here? I think it depends on the context of where Tzeva'ot' is mentioned.
The Gemera in Chagigah 16b says:

וריש לקיש אמר: ״ה׳ צבאות שמו״ — אדון הוא בצבא שלו.

And Reish Lakish said: He expounded the verse: “The Lord of hosts is His name” (Isaiah 48:2); He is the Master in His host.
Also in Brachot 31b:

אמרה חנה לפני הקדוש ברוך הוא: רבונו של עולם, מכל צבאי צבאות שבראת בעולמך קשה בעיניך שתתן לי בן אחד?

Rabbi Elazar explains that Hannah said before the Holy One, Blessed be He: Master of the Universe, are You not the Lord of the Hosts, and of all of the hosts and hosts of creations that You created in Your world, is it difficult in Your eyes to grant me one son?
Also in Rashi in Beresheit 1:16:

עַל יְדֵי שֶׁמִּעֵט אֶת הַלְּבָנָה הִרְבָּה צְבָאָיהָ לְהָפִיס דַּעְתָּהּ

Because He diminished the moon, He increased its attendant hosts to mollify it (Genesis Rabbah 6:4).
In these examples and many more, there is a common denominator based on what it says here that "Tzeva-ot refers to Hashem as He is manifest in the lower worlds, the worlds of Separateness. Tzeva-ot contains the word tzava, meaning "army" or "host", and ot, meaning "sign". (So to fully see if this klal works we would have to all examples where Tzeva'ot' comes up). Assuming this definition is true, then in the context of the first Bracha in Brachot Kriat Shema in Aravit which talks about Hashem creating luminaries and setting them up in their right time, etc, its appropriate to use Tzeva'ot'which talks about Hashem being manifest in the physical world and being a master of the army of luminaries in the heavens and in the universe. That name just fits the context of the bracha.

+1 for effort. Some remaining questions - why don't we say צבאות by morning birchot kriyat Shema? Unless you count it from Kedusha there? Why is it a double Name and not just צבאות ?

Good questions. I think we do, when we say, פינות  צבאות קדושים רממי שד-י. For why it's a double name, the Gemera in Chagigah 16b says וריש לקיש אמר: ״ה׳ צבאות שמו אדון הוא בצבא שלו, this means, "The Lord (master) of hosts is His name” meaning He is master of hosts, so this could mean that Hashems name (yud kei vav kei) gets the adjective/title of צבאות, describing Hashem (yud kei vav kei) as צבאות, hope this makes sense

פינות צבאות קדושים is not a name? And yes, makes sense (as much as that perek of Chagiga makes sense to mere mortals like me)

Ya your right, so maybe its as you said that we count it from kedusha

Or maybe we don't, because it is referring to stars mainly (like Rashi in your answer and
יהושע ק said similar)

Ya right, so I guess in some contexts צבאות means Hashem's name, and some not, in our case its an adjective to Hashem (yud kei vav kei) being a host over stars at night, which would also explain why we don't say צבאות in the morning

Note Rambam had the girsa as you presented, but other rishonim had the girsa that we paskin צבאות is not holy.
